# SimpleXML parser error: "Huge input lookup"

Tags: php, simplexml

I am using PHP for the first time. I am getting the following error on running the PHP file:

```
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 35909: parser error : internal error: Huge input lookup in /home/alisverispasaji/public_html/system/xml/minikoli/test.php on line 8

PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): p;lt;img src=&amp;amp;quot;/UserFiles/FCK/image/prima hangisi(1).jpg&amp;amp;quot; class in /home/alisverispasaji/public_html/system/xml/minikoli/test.php on line 8

PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string():                                                                                ^ in /home/alisverispasaji/public_html/system/xml/minikoli/test.php on line 8

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function children() on boolean in /home/alisverispasaji/public_html/system/xml/minikoli/test.php on line 20
```

How I can solve this error?

test.php:

```
<?php
ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0');
error_reporting(-1);

function simplexml_load_file_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($ch)); // <--- line 8
    return $xml;
}

$url = 'xml link';

$xml = simplexml_load_file_curl($url);

$veri = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
$veri .= '
<Urunler>';

foreach($xml->children() as $urun) { // <--- line 20
```

Comment: Looks like your input file may be too large, or references a source that is too large. Look at the first error message, that's causing the rest of the errors.

Comment: What should I do? What should I investigate ?

Comment: Check the size of the XML file. How much memory is PHP allowed to use on your server? Getting that info will help figure it out. Also, you might want to test with a smaller XML file. If that works, then you know what the issue is.

Answer (score 24):

Problem Solved

Find ;

`$xml = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($ch));`

Change ;

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($ch), 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_PARSEHUGE);
```